# I get "You are not authorized to access this page" when I try to load a view with Ajax

Tags: views, hooks, ajax

I am trying to load a view with Ajax, showing it in a specific `<div>`. I always get the Ajax message, "You are not authorized to access this page." My code is the following one:

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_menu().
*/
function custom_api_menu() {
  $items['ajaxgettip/nojs/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'custom_api_test_ajax',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback'   => TRUE,

      );
  $items['ajaxgettip/ajax/%'] = array(
     'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver',
     'access callback'   => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}


function custom_api_test_ajax($nid) {

   $viewName = 'tip';   
   $args = array($nid); 
   $displayId = 'block_1'; 
   $view = views_embed_view($viewName, $displayId, $args);
   //return drupal_json(array('test'=>$res));
   ajax_deliver($view);     
}
```

I am creating a link as follows:

```
<?php
    $link = array(
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#title' => t('something'),
        '#href' => 'ajaxgettip/ajax/114', #Hard coded nid at the end of path, just for testing
        '#ajax' => array(
            'wrapper' => 'ajax-response-goes-here',
            'method' => 'replace',
            'effect' => 'fade',
        ),
    );

$output = "<div id='ajax-response-goes-here'>Some HTML and stuff</div>" . drupal_render($link);
print $output;
?>
```

I don't have an idea about what I did wrong, and I have read a whole lot of documentation. Who can help me?

Comment: I think you miss 'page arguments' in hook_menu

Answer (score 1):

Try with `page arguments` in hook_menu:

```
function custom_api_menu() {
  $items['ajaxgettip/nojs/%'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'custom_api_test_ajax',
      'page arguments' => array(2),
      'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  $items['ajaxgettip/ajax/%'] = array(
      'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver',
      'page arguments' => array(2),
      'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `access callback` if you're returning `true`. It should be a string function name or don't specify it at all. Also check if $nid is being passed to the delivery callback function.

Edit: Sorry for bad answer, according to the comments this answer received, you do need to specify `access callback` as a function or `true`.

Comment: That's not true, you do need to specify an `access callback`. It will default to `user access` otherwise, in which case the `access arguments` must be set. The [`hook_menu()` docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) has all the info

Comment: Correct me when I am wrong, but I thing the option "'access callback'   => TRUE" means, that anybody has access.
I don't think that the problem occurs because of the fact that the $nid variable is empty: When I access the path 'ajaxgettip/ajax/114' directly (the last part of it is a existing nid), I get the same message as mentioned above:

[...]"ajaxCallback":"overlay-ajax"}},"merge":true},{"command":"alert","text":"You are not authorized to access this page."}]

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs you are correct

"access callback": A function returning TRUE if the user has access rights to this menu item, and FALSE if not. It can also be a boolean constant instead of a function

UPDATE: clearing the cache did it for me. (Now I've got to figure-out why I didn't think of that before)

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_menu().
*/
function custom_api_menu() {
  $items['ajaxgettip/nojs/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'custom_api_test_ajax',
    'page argument' => array(1,2),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback'   => TRUE,

      );
  $items['ajaxgettip/ajax/%'] = array(
     'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver',
      ) +  $items['ajaxgettip/nojs/%'];
  return $items;
}


function custom_api_test_ajax($ajax, $nid) {

   $ajax_true = $ajax === 'ajax';

   $viewName = 'tip';   
   $args = array($nid); 
   $displayId = 'block_1'; 
   $view = views_embed_view($viewName, $displayId, $args);

if ($ajax_true) {
    $commands = array();

    $commands[] = ajax_command_append('#ajax-response-goes-here', '<div>' . $view. '</div>');

    return array(
      '#type' => 'ajax',
      '#commands' => $commands,
    );
  }
  else {
    // Else show the page when nojs page is accessed instead. 
  }

}
```